# Clipper tool problem in QGIS when it was used to clip JPEG

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

If I draw a vector，that vector can also be used to clip an image (JPEG)，right?

In QGIS I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\widgetPluginBase.py", 
line 88, in onFinished self.base.onFinished(exitCode, status) 
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\GdalTools\tools\dialogBase.py", 
line 205, in onFinished msg = unicode(self.process.readAllStandardError()) 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Even changing the saving style into jpeg, it still doesn't work.

Comment: What kind of vector did you draw? Did you draw a polygon? Are your vector's RS and the RSs of the project and of the JPG image the same?

Comment: Output directory/name of both files have special characters? Like *ñ, à, é,* etc..

Comment: i draw the border of researching area，yes，that is a polygen，and the projection is already set the same when i create the new shp